# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in [{}]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model created as follows

```
var AddressSchema = new Schema({
  category: {type: String,  default: 'home'},
  lines: {type: String },
  city: {type: String}  
});


/**
 * Employee Schema
 */
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,

    default: Date.now
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  address: [AddressSchema],
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

Following is the code in controller.js

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  console.log('in create');
  var employee = new Employee(req.body);
  employee.user = req.user;
  var address = new Address(req.body.address);
  employee.address = [address];
  console.log(employee);
  console.log(req.body);

  employee.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

      return res.status(500).json({
        error: 'Cannot save the employee'
      });
    }
    res.json(employee);

  });
};
```

Log written in my console is

```
{ user: 5493dabf682b42be6af784b1,
  name: 'santhu',
  _id: 5495010203fa1e000068808b,
  address: [ { _id: 5495010203fa1e000068808c, category: 'home' } ],
  created: Sat Dec 20 2014 10:24:26 GMT+0530 (IST) }
{ name: 'santhu', address: '{}' }
[TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {}]
```

Why am I getting this error? I searched for this error and it happens when I try to save string when it expects object. I am saving proper object as you can see in logs. Why am I still facing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because your req.body contains address: '{}' which is string not array and not object if you write

```
 var body={ name: 'santhu', address: []}; //and not { name: 'santhu', address: '{}'}
 var employee = new Employee(body);
```

it will work fine

Comment: in the example I have shown, I already replaced the address attribute before saving. Why does it still give the error?

Comment: because you write var employee = new Employee(req.body); and this gives error

Comment: why was it still printing if there is error in that line. as it went ahead and printed the logs present after that line, i thought that line is fine but error is during save. Am I wrong?

Comment: during save there are no errors because you changed employee.address in this line employee.address = [address]; and at save time adress is not sting.if you won't change adress you will recieve error at save time